# Incomplete DateTime to a complete DateTime comparison

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I have a data type column in my SQL Server database.
And it's signature is following: date (yyyy-mm-dd) thus another column with tinyint representing the hour.
While another table contains a full datetime column (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff) There are no mm,ss,fff values. Everything is at 0. But hour is there..

I need to compare these two with Entity Framework.

*I know how it would be easy with two datetimes, but it's just how it is*

Now I have a Model in my C# code.
And they are both DateTime type. And I don't know how to compare them correctly.
It would be great, if I could make an anonymous type, where I could add this tinyint (or byte in C#) to this new (another DateTime) and add hour from the hour column.
But..

```
The property 'System.DateTime.Hour' has no setter
```

I don't know how to do this. And there is not that much info on Internet regarding this.

Is it really incomparable? Or there is a way to do this?

Comment: Which EF version are you using? Please choose the correct tag.

Comment: Within an EF Linq expression like a `Where` clause this is most likely impossible without client-side evaluation. Unless you adjust/extend the schema to provide comparable types, either computing a datetime for the string+tinyint, or computing a comparable int value for both (yyyyMMddhh) then the querying cannot leverage indexing. Client-side evaluation you can DateTime.Parse the string date, then AddHours the tiny int)

Comment: Why not add a calculated column (or a view) that simply combines the date and hour values into a single datetime value? You can then compare the two values directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want to do but:
If you want to add hours to an existing DateTime, you need to add a TimeSpan to this DateTime.

```
var date = DateTime.Now;

date = date + TimeSpan.FromHours(5); // adds 5 hours to the date
```

You can just replace the "5" by your tinyint value.

**Edit**
As you seems to struggle a bit understanding my simple example, a code closer than the one you should have on your side:

```
DateTime alreadyCompleteDate = ... // get the value from your database complete datetime column

DateTime incompleteDate = ... // get the value from your database incomplete datetime column
int hours = ... // get the number of hours to add to incompleteDate from your database tinyint column

DateTime completeDateTime = incompleteDate + TimeSpan.FromHours(hours);

// or whatever comparison you willing to do
var comparisonResult = alreadyCompleteDate < completeDateTime; // this works
```

Comment: You mean. Add a static variable on my code. 
That it's output will have a dependency on the current worldwide time ? 
Are you serious..

Comment: That code is just showing you how to add a number of hours to a DateTime.  The values would come from your database.

Comment: Yea, like obviously you won't use 5 as in my example, you just replace the 5 from my code example by the variable holding your hour column value ...
This would give you a complete DateTime with year month day : hh mm ss that you can now compare with your other complete DateTime.